# iOS where and when to fetch server data for view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller which needs to display data that is pulled from the server.

Normally I load the data I need from within this view controller via a server api adapter singleton.

But recently I've been thinking maybe it's better to load the data from outside the VC and then tell the VC when new data is available.  This way the VC isn't dependent on the server fetching code.

Or in other words:

Right now

1. Present the VC
2. In the VC's viewDidLoad call the server api singleton and fetch the data

Alternative

1. Call the server api singleton and fetch the data
2. Present the VC
3. When the server data is ready, tell the VC and pass in the data

In your experience which is the better approach and why?  Are there any other approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My basic flow, which works really well.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //some code
    [self loadAPIData]
}


-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
        //cancel api operation
    }
}

-(void) loadAPIData
{
    //Call Api and show UIActivityIndicatorView
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is the flow I currently use as well.  I was just wondering if maybe loading the data externally would be better in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to present viewController first then fetch data and finally to show data on viewController. While fetching data, you can put a loading status HUD on VC, users always know your app are working.

There is one problem in your second way, fetching data first then present VC, if fetching data failed, user's touch/tap action will have no effect, users may think your app is not working. This is a bad user experience.

Comment: The user experience is the same either way because the user sees the view controller appear and then needs to wait for the content to be loaded.  But you're right, if loading externally then the progress is harder to convey, so it looks like the first approach makes more sense.